# Initialize All pages in TestBase page Correct or Wrong habit?

Tags: java, selenium

i'm new to Selenium and Java and trying to figure out some things. The questing is straightforward, is it a good habit to initialize all the pages of an application from TestBase? e.g.

```
public class TestBase {

    protected static WebDriver driver;
    protected static PageBase base;
    protected static HomePage home;


    private void initPages()
    {
        base = new PageBase();
        base.setUpWebDriver(driver);
        home = new HomePage();
        home.setUpWebDriver(driver);
    }

    private void webDriverSetUp()
    {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private void webDriverClose() throws InterruptedException {
        if(driver!=null)
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.close();
        }
    }


    public void webDriverInit()
    {
        webDriverSetUp();
        initPages();
    }

    public void webDriverTerminate() throws InterruptedException {
        webDriverClose();
    }

}
```

or not, so every time you have to pass the driver to the page you want to test.
Is the load so big that it could cause problem during test execution?
Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Do not `initialize` all your page objects at the start, what if your application keeps growing.However this could potential slow down all your tests in the Automation test suite.

Comment: @KajalKundu, thanks for the answer, is any other way except PageFactory?

Comment: Try to use `Methods` return other `PageObjects`

Answer (score 0):

So it looks as if you are spinning up two separate drivers at the same time. One for the PageBase and one for HomePage. I strongly recommend that you only launch one driver executable at one time, unless you are multi-threading or using selenium grid. Or are they just adding a reference of the BaseTest driver to some field in the PageObjects? Not sure either way from the above code.

Also why do you have driver setup methods on the base page and in the base test? (page.setUpWebDriver() vs test.webDriverSetUp()) Little confused by that. I would handle all driver setup in the base test (along with all direct references to it). Move anything related to that out of basepage, in my opinion. Also, I may be misinterpreting that.

Also, I would remove the instances of home and base page from the TestBase. Instead, if you are NOT using multithreading and have no intent to, I would use singletons for page objects. Have the page object classes provide a static property that points to an instance of the page object, and store them all there in each page object. Additionally, the base page should be accessible from home page by default. You are extending it, right? That should not need an instance anywhere.

Singleton's have the added bonus of making it super easy to spin up something as needed. A sort of lazy-loading type process. The property that supplies the static self object should initialize anything on the page when it is referenced, and only then. Also, you may want to add logic that sets a flag to tell a page that it is dirty. If the webdriver navigates or refreshes, that flag should tell all page objects (if you have your PO's store IWebElement references) that it should re-get the entire page of elements if referenced again - which prevents stale element errors.

Although these are assumptions based on what I am reading, without the other source code, so ignore anything that is an incorrect assumption here.

Singleton example based on my suggestion above; kind of pseudo code:

```
public class LoginPage : BasePage {

    public static LoginPage Instance {
        get {
            if(_loginPage == null || BaseTest.IsDirty) {
                _loginPage = new LoginPage();
            }
            return _loginPage;
        }
    }
    private _loginPage;

    public IWebElement PasswordField ...
    ... any selenium logic that auto-populates values of page elements.

}
```

I have a strong preference to avoid populating page objects with values automatically. I personally prefer to make PageObjects a single repository of a page's element's identifying selectors, rather than instance of the actual object. It eliminates the majority of instances where you need to worry about stale elements and tracking that.

Comment: PO is something like this, public static String SEARCH = "//input[@title='Search']"; and i have no PageFactory to initialize all the elements of the pages, so i need a way to do that. One way to do that is in the TestBase...which is wrong......and the other one each time i want to test a page to create the appropriate instance and pass the drive....i'm know to this and spinning around to figure it out, thanks for the answer by the way